# elliptic estimate and Sobolev inequality for sections of holomorphic line bundles

Tags: differential-geometry, complex-geometry, kahler-manifolds

I'm reading *《Gromov-Hausdorff limits of Kähler manifolds and algebraic geometry》* by *Simon Donaldson & Sun Song*. In their Section 2, named *Complex differential geometry: the Hormander technique*, they mention the following elliptic estimate and Sobolev inequality for sections of holomorphic line bundles:

$(U^n,J,\omega)$ is a complex manifold, $u_*\in U$ and $D\subset U$ is an open neighborhood of $u_*$. $\Lambda\to U$ is a $C^{\infty}$ Hermitian line bundle with curvature $-\sqrt{-1}\omega$. Fix $p>2n$.

Then for any smooth section $\tau$ of $\Lambda$ over a neighborhood of $\bar{D}$ we have

the elliptic estimate: $\|\tau\|_{L_1^p\left(D_0\right)} \leqslant C\left(\|\bar{\partial} \tau\|_{L^p(D)}+\|\tau\|_{L^2(D)}\right)$.

and

the Sobolev inequality:$\left|\tau\left(u_*\right)\right| \leqslant C\|\tau\|_{L_1^p\left(D_0\right)}$.

I don't know where can I find the proof of these two formulas? And I'm not familiar with the Hormander technique mentioned here, can anyone give me some reference? Thanks in advance.

Comment: If I remember correctly, you can find it in Hormander's book [here](https://www.sciencedirect.com/bookseries/north-holland-mathematical-library/vol/7/suppl/C)